# How do I reference one model from another model using aws API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

Say I have a Model:

```
"Pet":{
  "type": "object"
  "properties": {
    "name":{"type":"integer"},
    "age":{"type":"integer"}
  }
}
```

And another model:

```
"Human":{
  "type": "object"
  "properties": {
    "name":{"type":"integer"},
    "age":{"type":"integer"},
    "pets":{
      "type":"array"
      "items": {
        <This is where my question is>
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How can I reference the Pet model in my human model?

With swagger I was able to say:

```
"$ref": "#/definitions/Pet"
```

but API Gateway seems to not allow it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you mean reference model outside swagger, you can do that by specifying the model with an absolute url like below

```
 {"type":"array","items":{"$ref":"https://apigateway.amazonaws.com/restapis/<rest_api_id>/models/Pet"}}
```

For swagger, this example from open api specification shows how to reference models within swagger - https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/examples/v2.0/json/petstore.json

```
"Pets": {
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
    "$ref": "#/definitions/Pet"
  }
```

Note that api gateway does not support 'default' response, so if you are trying to import the above petstore.json example, you need to remove the "default" fields.

Comment: This is the first post that actually notes that AWS is an external service while swagger routes are internal.. finally!!!! you got my upvote :)

Comment: The unsupported OpenAPI 3.0 features go past the `default` - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-known-issues.html#api-gateway-known-issues-rest-apis

Comment: Just for the sake of the link, the answer is what https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=697388 mentions.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want single values (not arrays), this works:

```
..
"properties": {
            "id": {
                "$ref": "https://apigateway.amazonaws.com/restapis/abcd1234/models/UserId"
            },
..
```

(It would be nice if this could be a relative URL rather than absolute, but I haven't found any mention of how to do this yet)

Comment: Is there still no way to make the above relative?