# How do I reference one model from another model with multiple definitions using aws API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, api-gateway

I am trying to reference a model using this:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-create-api-step-by-step.html#getting-started-models-add-models

```
"deets": {
"$ref":"https://apigateway.amazonaws.com/restapis/<rest_api_id>/models/stuff
}
```

The problem is stuff has multiple definitions in it. How do I reference just the one?

For example:
stuff
   -box
   -jar
   -cup

I have tried adding /box but I then receive "Invalid model specified: Validation Result: warnings : [], errors : [Model reference must be in canonical form]"

I have read [How do I reference one model from another model using aws API Gateway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37823112/how-do-i-reference-one-model-from-another-model-using-aws-api-gateway) and it solves half the problem, the actual reference, but doesn't say how to reference a specific definition.